# Is this misuse of a singleton?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I've read all about singletons and how they pose the threat of being an anti pattern if misused. So I wanted to get a second opinion as to whether or not this is a misuse of the pattern.

Essentially I have 5 repositories. All they do is store data. In reality, all of the data they store is closely related, I've only made them 5 different repositories so that the classes are short and easy to pick through. I know that if I make each of these repositories a singleton, I can say good bye to any maintainable unit tests; however; I had this idea that I could make each repository a normal class and then make a singleton that simply stores 1 copy of each of the repositories.

This way I can fulfill the requirements of there only being one central location for the data per instance of my program but I can also unit test each repository in some of the operations it needs to perform.

Comment: Well, are there actual "requirements of there only being one central location for the data per instance of my program"? Or do you simply have no use case (yet) for multiple repository-groups?

Comment: "This way I can fulfill the requirements of there only being one central location for the data per instance of my program"  Since this is your program and you control the code, why not just instantiate one instance of each class?  You don't need to be afraid of more instances being instantiated, because you are writing the code.

Comment: Well, in reality its a web application and the variables I'm looking at would be stored in the application scope under normal circumstances. I just personally felt it'd be easier to maintain if they were singleton's as opposed to application scope variables.

Comment: The easiest way to maintain one set of data that is shared globally by multiple threads and/or processes is a database.  The DBMS handles all of the concurrency issues for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you may be able to unit-test repositories, but you will certainly have a hard time unit testing all the other code which depends on these repositories. Singleton couples the calling code to the one-and-only implementation through direct access scattered all over your code base. And even if there really is a single copy of your data, i.e. an in-memory database of some kind, there is no reason to let other layers know this.

Also, by "making them a simple class" (I presume you mean, by exposing a public constructor?), you are defeating the whole point of a singleton, i.e. the notion that no other code can instantiate a different instance.

If repositories are a dependency for a certain class, then simply pass them using constructor injection and make your testing easier. This will allow you to easily mock each repository when testing classes from the domain layer.

Comment: Agreed, consider using an IOC container to inject the repositories. You can control their lifetime in the compositional root, specifying singleton for now with the option to alter that decision later quite easily.

Comment: @jayint32: thanks for the comment! I agree, but I usually keep the container part out of the picture, since the best place to use it is [at the composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), meaning that all other parts of the code should just work as if there were no container at all (I try to avoid the service locator pattern), and it's not needed for unit testing. Even a poor-man's DI will work perfectly well, IMHO, after the rest of the app is constructed properly.

Answer (score 0):

What constitutes misuse of a singleton (or it's overall usefulness at all) is one of those religious arguments that has no clear-cut answer.

However, you have hit on one of the major drawbacks of the singleton pattern, and that is that it complicates unit tests.  Worse, it generally degrades the overall maintainability of your code.

Consider this possible replacement;

```
   public interface IRepositoryContainer
   {
      IRepository GetRepository<T>() where T : IRepository;
   }

   public partial class App : Application, IRepositoryContainer
   {
      private List<IRepository> repositories =
         new List<IRepository>() { new MyRespository() };

      public IRepository GetRepository<T>() 
         where T : IRepository
      {
         return repositories.Where(t => t is T).SingleOrDefault();
      }
```

then where before you would have called a singleton, instead...

```
     IRepository repo = (Application.Current as IRepositoryContainer).GetRepository<MyRespository>();
```

Just a thought, but there is already only one instance of the application, interfaces can help you solve this problem.

(yes, the example code above is wpf, but the principals should apply)

Comment: How exactly would this simplify testing? I cannot see a single benefit from using the `Application.Current` singleton, to access a custom instance derived from an `Application`, and add data access functionality to that completely unrelated class. And, it's still a singleton.